# convert many rows to same columns

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to build results converted from rows into columns and tried the MAX  and PIVOT, which I do not want as these create duplicate columns (unless my queries are wrong). So I want it to stay in belong same columns.
I am using ORACLE SQL Developer.
Here is the example I am trying to find the correct statement.

Data from `Purchased` table:

| Customer_ID | Last_Name | First_name | Product | Purchased | Service | Warranty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | Smith | John | Car | 01/06/2007 | 02/06/2008 | 10 |
| 50 | Smith | John | SUV | 03/11/2005 | 04/11/2006 | 15 |
| 50 | Smith | John | Truck | 07/05/2004 | 08/05/2005 | 20 |
| 20 | McGregor | Katie | Car | 11/01/2006 | 12/01/2006 | 10 |
| 11 | Yang | Karen | Car a | 21/07/2006 | 22/08/2007 | 10 |
| 11 | Yang | Karen | Car b | 10/09/2005 | 11/09/2006 | 10 |
| 90 | Wilkins | Melissa | SUV | 25/05/2005 | 26/05/2006 | 10 |
| 90 | Wilkins | Melissa | Car a | 10/07/2005 | 11/07/2006 | 10 |
| 90 | Wilkins | Melissa | 4WD | 05/11/2003 | 06/11/2004 | 15 |
| 90 | Wilkins | Melissa | Car b | 29/03/2001 | 30/03/2002 | 10 |
| 135 | Barnes | Tom | 4WD | 02/08/2008 | 03/08/2009 | 15 |

The output that I want result like this:

| Customer_ID | Last_Name | First_name | 4WD | Car | Car a | Car b | SUV | Truck | Warranty_4WD | Warranty_Car | Warranty_CarA | Warraty_CarB | Warranty_SUV | Warranty_Truck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | Smith | John |  | 01/06/2007 |  |  | 03/11/2005 | 07/05/2004 |  | 10 |  |  | 15 | 20 |
| 20 | McGregor | Katie |  | 11/01/2006 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | Yang | Karen |  |  | 21/07/2006 | 10/09/2005 |  |  |  | 10 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 90 | Wilkins | Melissa | 05/11/2003 |  | 10/07/2005 | 29/03/2001 | 25/05/2005 |  | 15 |  | 10 |  | 10 |  |
| 135 | Barnes | Tom | 02/08/2008 |  |  |  |  |  | 15 |  |  |  |  |  |

Would be appreciated your help!

Comment: thank you to @AEM and the admin for updating my question and make it nicer than before!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this single table it works well with `Max(decode)` statements, as follows:

```
  SELECT customer_id,
         last_name,
         first_name,
         max(decode(product,'4WD', Purchased )) as 4WD ,
         max(decode(product,'Car', Purchased )) as car ,
         max(decode(product,'Car a', Purchased )) as car_a ,
         -- ==> repeat same for other rest product then different for warranty
         max(decode(product,'4WD', warranty )) as Warranty_4WD ,
         max(decode(product,'Car', warranty )) as Warranty_car 
    FROM purchased
GROUP BY customer_id,
         last_name,
         first_name
```

However, if you are planning to use this table with another table to join more than two tables, you need to use a `WITH` statement depending on the output result from your end.